# belongs_to and references actually create relations in table?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, foreign-key-relationship

I am in ruby on rails 4.2. Now working with relation and try to create one-one relation ship between Instructor and Office_Assignments shown in the ContosoUniversity of .net MVC sample. Please click [here](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) to see the relation details.

In ruby i am following [this](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) tutorial.

I added Instructor model using the following command.

```
rails g model Instructor LastName:string FirstMidName:string HireDate:date
```

and then create Office_Assignments like below

```
rails g model OfficeAssignments Location:string
```

Now i updated the model classes like below for relations.

```
class Instructor < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :office_assignment
end

class OfficeAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```

In the create_office_assignments migration file i changed like below for relations

```
class CreateOfficeAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :office_assignments do |t|
      t.belongs_to :instructor
      t.string :Location
      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

So when i use migrate command, tables created and columns created like below in mysql

**mysql>describe office_assignments;**

```
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id            | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| instructor_id | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| Location      | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| created_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at    | datetime     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but when i check the relationship like below, it didn't create any foreign key relation ship.

**mysql> select table_name, column_name, constraint_name, referenced_table_name, referenced_column_name  from information_schema.key_column_usage where constraint_schema = 'ContosoUniversity';**

```
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| table_name         | column_name | constraint_name          | referenced_table_name | referenced_column_name |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
| instructors        | id          | PRIMARY                  | NULL                  | NULL                   |
| office_assignments | id          | PRIMARY                  | NULL                  | NULL                   |
| schema_migrations  | version     | unique_schema_migrations | NULL                  | NULL                   |
| students           | id          | PRIMARY                  | NULL                  | NULL                   |
+--------------------+-------------+--------------------------+-----------------------+------------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Here i am confused why not create foreign key or i missed anything in my migration or some where? also i need to set the primary key and foreign key as same column. I read about add_foriegn_key, but didn't understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run

```
rails g model Instructor LastName:string FirstMidName:string HireDate:date 

rails g model OfficeAssignments Location:string instructor:references
```

will create DB level constraints, add belongs_to/has_one to models, than check generated migration file. There you can also add on_update: 'delete' and so on.

Comment: great that works. but how i create same column as primary and foreign key

Comment: I'm quite new to Rails my self, but from my expedience, id field should be free of some meaning or logic to rely on, it's just to be there as a rule and be a primary key. there's no reason for anyone to override that default convention. If you do so you than you will have  to change this throughout a code. Just leave it be.

Comment: but if you really wish than edit migration file to `create_table :office_assignments, id: false do |t| t.primary_key: "instructor_id`

Answer (score 1):

Rails doesn't create foreign key constraints by default (it's only since 4.2 that you've been able to do this without using raw sql or an extra gem)

If you put

```
add_foreign_key :office_assignments, :instructors
```

In a migration then it will add the constraint (there's also a variant you can use with a change table block if my memory is correct)

In rails 4.2.1 (not yet released) you'll be able to do

```
t.belongs_to :instructor, foreign_key: true
```

To do it all in one go

Comment: ok i got that and i working in 4.2 but how i create same column as primary and foreign key

Comment: @Akhil you can pass options for that sort of stuff to add foreign key and to the association methods in your model, but it's not quite clear to me what you want

Comment: thanks, but i need instructor_id as the primary_key in office_assignments and also the same column will be the foreign key

Answer (score 0):

I changed my migration like below and also in model to include my primary key

```
class CreateOfficeAssignments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :office_assignments, :id => false do |t|
      t.primary_key :Instructor_Id
      t.string :Location

      t.timestamps null: false
    end

    add_foreign_key :office_assignments, :instructors, column: :Instructor_Id, primary_key: "Id"
  end
end


class OfficeAssignment < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_primary_key :Instructor_Id
  belongs_to :instructor
end
```